# Different root folder depending on the URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need your help guys. I've been searching everywhere on how to get what I want and I can't seem to find the correct answer.

I want to use different root folders depending on the URL.

```html
/
  /site
    /index.php
  /panels
    /employer
      /index.php
    /admin
      /index.php
```

So if I will search `www.domain.com`, it should use `/site` folder. Else if I'm going to search `www.domain.com/employer`, it should use `/panels/employer` folder. And lastly, if I'm going to search `www.domain.com/admin`, it should use `/panels/admin` folder.

I don't know if this is possible and I would surely appreciate it if you guys can help me out!

**UPDATED**

Here is the current code, thanks to @devROYAL.

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ panels/admin/$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^employer/(.*)$ panels/employer/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

The only problem in here is that, when I search domain.com, it does not use the folder /site.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna love this magical line... :D

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ panels/admin/$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^employer/(.*)$ panels/employer/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

**Updated**

If you wants to show **index.php** from some **subDir** (let's say `sites`), then use this

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /sites/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Awesome! The employer and admin is working now, and it would be great if when searching www.domain.com, it will use the root folder /site. Is that possible?

Comment: Cool! Is it possible if you can help me with that? Thanks! :)

Comment: The index page shows now, but the other pages like www.domain.com/index2.php results in to a 404 page. Do you know what the problem is? Thank you!

Comment: you need to put the `index` to top of all RewriteRules and `admin` & `employer` below that... If you need further assistance move to Chat

Comment: Yep, I did that already as well, but the problem is still there :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212394/discussion-between-david-maranga-and-devroyal).

Comment: i think your problem is with other pages not with `admin` and `employer` stuff right ?